# A proportion question regarding video game players

Tags: probability, statistics, percentages

I am trying to find a proportion of console players that play a certain number of call of duty games. 40% of players use xbox, 50% use playstation, and 10% use wii u. Of those who play on xbox, 60% play more than 3 games. Of those who play on playstation, 15% play more than 3 games. Of those who play on wii u, 0% play more than 3 games. What proportion of the players playing on wii u play less than 3 games?

So far, I Let total players be 100.

Then no. of players that use XBOX, Playstation and Wii U are 40 (40% of 100), 50 (50% of 100), and 10 respectively.

The no. of players that play more than 3 games on XBOX, Playstation and Wii U are 24 (60% of 40) , 25 (50% of 50) and 0 respectively.

The no. of players that play less than 3 games on XBOX, Playstation and Wii U are 16 (40-24), 25 (50-25) and 10 (10-0) respectively.

The proportion of the players who plays less than 3 games on Wii U is given as: 10/100 = 0.1 (my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you read the question right? It's impossible to answer if taken literally.

"Of those who play on wii u, 0% play more than 3 games. What proportion of the players playing on wii u play less than 3 games?"

You cannot find out how many players play exactly 3 games, so there's no way to answer the question.

If you play exactly 3 games, you don't play more than 3 games, but you also don't play less than 3 games. You play exactly 3 games.